# Is there a way to see what my code looks like after type erasure?

Tags: java, generics

I would like to know what tool can be used to view code after type erasure.  For example, I'd like  to see what the following code looks like after type erasure. I know that generic type information is stripped prior to final compilation, replacing type references with Object or boundary types, creating bridge methods, etc. I want to see the source code after the erasure process takes place.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Predicate<Object> objPredicate = (Object c) -> c.toString().length() > 2 ;
    Predicate<? super Integer> predicate = objPredicate;
    Number n = Integer.valueOf(22);
    System.out.println(predicate.test(n)); //this line does not compile
  }
```

[If compiling code is required to see an erasure inspection tool work on the example, the non-compiling line can be omitted or `n` can be cast to `Integer`]

Comment: that's an interesting question, may I ask why you need that information though? if you are simply asking why that code not compile - than iis rather easy to answer via `PECS`.

Comment: @Eugene I wanted to study, empirically,  how so-called input variables (upper bound) seemingly are declared as  output variables (lower bound) in Functional interfaces.  And I am often at a loss to predict just how the erasure process works exactly.  If I pass String to a Predicate.test method that accepts ? super CharSequence, why should it compile?  Why shouldn’t it, if I’m just testing against the CharSequence interface?  Looking under the hood is helpful.

Comment: I understand. At the same time I disagree, those are simply folowing the PECS rule. how the "erasure works exactly" is in the JLS, not sure what you are missing, to be fair. Its not a very pleasant read, but its there, as the other answer has already showed. This is not something you study empirically, imo.

Comment: What is PECS?  Is  this resource that is more helpful for predicting erasure, than studying the behavior of the compiler directly?  I want to check that out.

Comment: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: @John Kugelman Martin Fowler!  What a metaphor to live by.  I was aware of this and I am building reflection based  validation that depends on being able to expect what's going to happen at runtime. And, thanks.

Comment: You can have a look at the following https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On github, I found the java-based open source gui tool [bytecode viewer](https://github.com/Konloch/bytecode-viewer) which did the job as follows:

```
 public static void main(String[] var0) {
      Predicate var1 = (var0x) -> {
         return var0x.toString().length() > 2;
      };
      Integer var3 = 22;
      System.out.println(var1.test(var3));
   }
```

To get this, I set the view menu to Pane 2/Fernflower/Java.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that generic type information is stripped prior to final compilation

This is not  quite true, as erasure is a part of the compilation process itself, not something that happens prior to compilation. i.e. erasure is not a transformation that happens on source code.

As such, there is no way (that I know of) to programmatically get a transformed version of the source code, but we can figure out what happens for simple examples like this by following the rules in [JLS 4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6):

> Type erasure is a mapping from types (possibly including parameterized
> types and type variables) to types (that are never parameterized types
> or type variables). We write |T| for the erasure of type T. The
> erasure mapping is defined as follows:
>
> - The erasure of a parameterized type (§4.5) G<T1,...,Tn> is |G|.
> - The erasure of a nested type T.C is |T|.C.
> - The erasure of an array type T[] is |T|[].
> - The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.
> - The erasure of every other type is the type itself.
>
> Type erasure also maps the signature (§8.4.2) of a constructor or method to a signature that has no parameterized types or type variables. The erasure of a constructor or method signature s is a signature consisting of the same name as s and the erasures of all the formal parameter types given in s.
>
> The return type of a method (§8.4.5) and the type parameters of a generic method or constructor (§8.4.4, §8.8.4) also undergo erasure if the method or constructor's signature is erased.
>
> The erasure of the signature of a generic method has no type parameters.

For your code snippet we get (ignoring trivial erasures):

```
Predicate<Object> -> Predicate
Predicate<? super Integer> -> Predicate
```

Yielding:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Predicate objPredicate = (Object c) -> c.toString().length() > 2 ;
    Predicate predicate = objPredicate;
    Number n = Integer.valueOf(22);
    System.out.println(predicate.test(n)); //this line does not compile
}
```

Furthermore, the erased signature of the `Predicate::test` method is:

```
boolean test​(Object t)
```

Comment: This is really helpful in understanding the compilation issue, because it's clear why inference is failing.  As regards a tool -- I am hoping that someone knowledgeable in reverse-compilation tools can weigh in on this.  I have heard there are tools that allow you to walk bytecode back to source, and it seems plausible they'd allow you to specify pre-generics versions.  I'm just not sure which tool, whether there is open source etc, e.g., if anyone has done this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very simple type like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Predicate<? super Integer> predicate = x -> x > 1;
}
```

it gets compiled with `invokedynamic`, like:

```
invokedynamic #7,  0  // InvokeDynamic #0:test:()Ljava/util/function/Predicate;
```

and if you look at the `BootstrapMethods`, the `MethodType` preserves (almost) all generic information (I don't think it can preserve the fact that there was a wildcard in use):

```
#41 (Ljava/lang/Integer;)Z
```

This reads as "takes an Integer, returns a boolean". So, in theory, it could be possible to re-construct the generic information back. I have tried `Intellij` to reconstruct the types from a `.class` file - and it does not preserve the generic types. I am not aware of a tool that would do that.

Comment: VERY helpful and led me to the JDK tool `javap`, which creates something if not exactly java source.   Note I am simply trying to strip out generics -- not put them back in -- so the Intellj viewer might work.

Answer (score 0):

I show you an example of why is not permitted what you expose in your question. When you put Predicate<? super Integer> the compiler only knows that the 'unknown' type is a supertype of Integer but not which of them.
The 'unknown' supertype in this case might be: Integer (the only that the compiler is secure to be), Number, Comparable, Serializable, Object.

```
Integer max = 10;
Predicate<Comparable<Integer>> comp = integer -> integer.compareTo(max) > 1;
Predicate<? super Integer> predicate = comp;
Number number = 3;

//This doesn't make sense since Number doesn't even implement Comparable 
comp.test(number); //Compilation error
```